# Cleaning Up Custom Write-Progress Information

Tags: powershell, console

I am using Write-Progress cmdlet to display a progress bar whilst executing diskpart in powershell (v5.0) command window on WinPE.

```
$HDDDisk=0
$commands=@()
$commands+="select disk " + 0
$commands+="clean"$commands | out-string | diskpart  | Where-Object { $_.Length -gt 0 } | `
Foreach-Object { Write-Progress -Activity "Disk $HDDDisk" -Status $_ -Id 1}
Write-Progress -Activity "Disk $HDDDisk" -Status "Complete" -Completed
```

After completing the diskpart I use the Expand-WindowsImage cmdlet to restore the windows image.  Expand-WindowsImage also uses write-progress to report progress as far as I can tell.

The problem I have is the information from the diskpart progress is not cleaned up correctly and the display information when Expand-WindowsImage is running appears as (Retyped) which is very confusing.

```
Disk 0
     DISKPART>
Operation
   Running
   [oooo
```

How to I cleanup / remove the diskpart write-progress information before starting the Expand-WindowsImage cmdlet?

Thanks

Stuart

Answer (score 0):

you can use `-currentOperation OuterLoop/InnerLoop` to separate two progress bars.

like:

```
Foreach-Object { Write-Progress -Activity "Disk $HDDDisk" -Status $_ -Id 1 -currentOperation InnerLoop}
Write-Progress -Activity "Disk $HDDDisk" -Status "Complete" -Completed -currentOperation OuterLoop
```